# Conectarse a una red WiFi en modo AP sin PASS usando Flutter

Tags: flutter, wifi, esp8266

Quiero desarrollar una aplicación móvil con Flutter para conectarme a una red WiFi desarrollada con el ESP8266 en modo AP.
He intentado usar con package *wifi_scan* y *wifi_iot* y su ejemplo para mostrar en una lista las redes WiFi cercanas mediante Flutter.
La idea es que cuando hace tap sobre la red WiFi hecha con el ESP8266 pueda conectarme.
Aparece un pop up "Desea conectarse...", desde console log dice que la red está conectada, pero no estoy teniendo éxito.
La única manera de conectarme es ir a Ajustes->Conexiones->WiFi y elegir el WiFi del ESP8266.
Luego hacer una conexión al AP del ESP a través del 192.168.4.1. **Nota: la red está abierta, no tiene password.**

**Ejemplo del Scan de los WiFi cercanos**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cuando hago TAP sobre la red, no tengo el *símbolo* de WiFI en la barra de estado**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Conexión establecidad a través Ajuste->Conexiones...**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
ListTile(
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
      leading: Icon(signalIcon),
      title: Text(title),
      subtitle: Text(widget.accessPoint.capabilities),
      onTap: () async {
          print(widget.accessPoint.ssid);
          bool connect = await WiFiForIoTPlugin.connect(
          widget.accessPoint.ssid,
          joinOnce: true,
          isHidden: false,
          withInternet: false,
          //password: 'none',
          security: NetworkSecurity.NONE,
        );
       print('Conected: $connect');
        await WiFiForIoTPlugin.forceWifiUsage(true);
        await WiFiForIoTPlugin.setEnabled(true);//, shouldOpenSettings: true);

        print(await WiFiForIoTPlugin.isConnected());
        setState(() {});
      },
    );
```

> The console log is: I/ViewRootImpl@1a848cbMainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 0 I/ViewRootImpl@1a848cbMainActivity: ViewPostIme pointer 1 I/flutter (23696): EM D/ConnectivityManager(23696): StackLog: [android.net.ConnectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.java:4598)] [com.alternadom.wifiiot.WifiIotPlugin.connectTo(WifiIotPlugin.java:1402)] [com.alternadom.wifiiot.WifiIotPlugin.access$400(WifiIotPlugin.java:54)] [com.alternadom.wifiiot.WifiIotPlugin$7.run(WifiIotPlugin.java:903)] D/ConnectivityManager(23696): StackLog: [android.net.ConnectivityManager.sendRequestForNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3925)] [android.net.ConnectivityManager.sendRequestForNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3967)] [android.net.ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:4167)] [com.alternadom.wifiiot.WifiIotPlugin.connectTo(WifiIotPlugin.java:1428)] [com.alternadom.wifiiot.WifiIotPlugin.access$400(WifiIotPlugin.java:54)] [com.alternadom.wifiiot.WifiIotPlugin$7.run(WifiIotPlugin.java:903)] I/flutter (23696): Conected: true I/flutter (23696): true